# How can i pass id in Dropdown selectionChange using angular4?

Tags: javascript, angular

This is my object(coming from api) populating in dropdown

```
[
  {Id: 1, Name: 'Hydrogen', symbol: 'H'},
  {ID: 2, Name: 'Helium',  symbol: 'He'},
  {ID: 3, Name: 'Lithium',  symbol: 'Li'},

];
```

Below I have my html code

```
<mat-form-field >
  <mat-select formControlName="Name" placeholder="Name" (selectionChange)="elementSelectionChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let element of Elements" [value]="element.Name">
      {{ element.Name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

When ever user select the Name `selectionChange` need to pass  and based on that ID next dropdown values i need to populate.

Here  i don't want to change `[value]="element.Name"` but when ever user select some Name in  dropdown i need to pass ID how can achieve this .

component.ts

```
elementSelectionChange(event) {

        console.log(event.value.ID);

  }
```

Comment: This is quite simple move onSelectionChange to the options. `<mat-option *ngFor="let element of Elements" [value]="element.Name"(onSelectionChange)="elementSelectionChange(element.id)">`

Comment: when i add above code i am getting value as name...i am not getting id@Swoox

Comment: Just out of curiosity: What's wrong with using `[value]="element.ID"`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all names are unique, you could just use `find()` to get the id of the selection:

```
elementSelectionChange(ev) {
  let value = this.Elements.find(x => x.Name === ev.value)
  console.log(value.ID);
}
```

Comment: object is coming from api

Comment: Yes, I got that. So you have all your objects in the `Elements` array, right?

Comment: yes and after getting value.ID i need to pass this vallue in another api@Alex

Comment: So yes, you have the id in `value.ID` in above example.